# issue in cygwin error like non-cygwin compatible make program?

Tags: cygwin, ocr

My question is when I am trying to compile my ocr code with the help of cygwin and android-ndk. then it show me error of non-cygwin compatible make program error.

when I am writing this command on cygwin:

```
/cygdrive/c/android-ndk-r6b/ndk-build
```

then it show me error like this:

```
ERROR : You are using a non-Cygwin Compatible Make program.
Currently using C:/cygwin/bin/make

To solve the issue , follow this steps :

1. Ensure that the Cygwin 'make' package is installed.
Note : You will nedd GNU Make 3.81 or later !

2. Define the GNUMAKE environment variable to point to it, as in :

     export GNUMAKE=usr/bin/make

3. Call 'ndk-build' again.
```

I am not using any space in path mean that my android-ndk path is "C:/android-ndk-r6b" so it do not contain any spaces.

Comment: What does this problem have to do with spaces?

Answer (score 0):

Shot in the dark here, but have you actually tried Defining the `GNUMAKE` variable, as suggested?

```
cd /cygdrive/c/android-ndk-r6b
export GNUMAKE=/usr/bin/make
./ndk-build
```